# jQuery datepicker causing errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, user-controls, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using a jQuery plugin for datepick (http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery.datepick.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.datepick.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

         $(function () {
             $(".mydatepicker").datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
         });
```

and keep running into this problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>
```

when I try to export some data in CSV file from that page.

Any ideas?!

I've tried a number of solutions from my search (e.g. updating  in web.config) but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The `Sys` in the Client side is part of the `asp:ScriptManager`.

So include the `asp:ScriptManager`, before the use of the Sys to remove your error.

Comment: I do have a asp:ScriptManager before my function for datepicker. I dont konw where I am getting that Sys from, as it only appears in the error but not in my actual .aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you using this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') 
        throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>
```

This is used when you are using `scriptmanager` into your application. 
Are you using `update panels` in you web page? 
If not remove the lines.

Script Manager Detail
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163354.aspx